# Get away with built-in dragging html elements

Tags: html, transparent

I have a problem with html-objects that moving when I´m dragging them, you know the transparent "ghost" -copy of the element that appears when you holding down the mouse and drag it. My problem is that it interrupt my mouse event. I have a image that should be able to move inside a div when you dragging it with the mouse. I have to events for that, first one for mousedown that trigger mousemove-event, mousemove handles the movement of the image. mousedown is no problem but when I´m moving the mouse with the button down the transparent "ghost" - copy of the elements appear and interrupt my mousemove-event. Is that any one how knows how to get around or fix this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this 12 years ago but if I remember right the solution was something like,

```js
imageElement.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

This should prevent the user from clicking and dragging on the image which means the browser won't add any visual effects.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a sample?

From what it sounds like, the first thing to check is that the events are actually being hit.  Writing messages out to `console` whenever each event fires should help prove or disprove that the events are occurring as-expected.

Answer (score 0):

Then you start your mousemove event, set a timeout for the appended class 'hide' in 0 ms. Its work.

```js
const dragAndDrop = () => {
    const card = document.querySelector('.dragDrop');
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
    const dragStart = function () {
    
    // i added timeout for appended class
        
       setTimeout(() => {
        this.classList.add('hide');
       }, 0);
    };
    const dragEnd = function () {
    
    // i added timeout for appended class
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.classList.remove('hide');
           }, 0);
    };
    const dragOver = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    const dragEnter = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.classList.add('hovered');
    }
    const dragLeave = function () {
        this.classList.remove('hovered');
    }
    const dragDrop = function () {
        this.append(card);
        this.classList.remove('hovered')
    }

    cells.forEach((cell) => {
        cell.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
        cell.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
        cell.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
        cell.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
    })

    card.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    card.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}

dragAndDrop()
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.block{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.card{
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;

    background-color: black;
    cursor: grab;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
.hovered {
    background-color: rgb(254, 164, 164);
}
```

```html
 <div class="block">
            <div draggable="true" class="drag dragDrop">
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="text">Hello, world</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).